# Cómo poner elemento circular en Boostrap

Tags: bootstrap-4

Estoy utilizando **Bootstrap** y quiero hacer un dashboard con algunos elementos que figuran en un *theme* de **Bootstrap** *(Spark – Responsive Admin Template*).
Cómo puedo agregar una imagen circular estadística como la que figura en dicho *theme*?
He revisado la documentación y no encuentro nada parecido.
[image: Spark – Responsive Admin Template]

Comment: Con imagen circular estadística te refieres a la gráfica de tipo torta?

Comment: Así es. La imagen del lado derecho de la imagen. El anillo de tres colores.

Comment: Eso es una gráfica, no creo que bootstrap tenga generador de graficas la verdad no lo sé, por que no usas una librería para generar la gráfica?

Comment: No existe un componente de bootstrap en la documentación que te permita hacerlo. Como dice Bender lo mejor es usar una librería. ¿Has probado chart.js? Tiene justo lo que necesitas (http://www.chartjs.org/samples/latest/charts/doughnut.html)